# Why am I getting error asking for create user template in rails 2 using authlhogic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, authlogic

I get theh following error:

> UsersController#create
>   (ActionView::MissingTemplate) "Missing
>   template users/create.erb in view path
>   app/views"

But I don't know why:  Here is my controller:

```
1 class UsersController < ApplicationController
  2 
  3   before_filter :require_no_user, :only => [:new, :create]
  4   before_filter :require_user, :only => [:show, :edit, :update]
  5 
  6   def new
  7     @user = User.new
  8   end
  9 
 10   def create
 11 
 12     @user = User.new(params[:user])
 13     debugger
 14     @user.save do |result|
 15       debugger
 16       if result
 17         debugger
 18         flash[:notice] = "Account registered!"
 19         debugger
 20         redirect_back_or_default campaign_path
 21       else
 22         debugger
 23         render :action => :new
 24       end
 25 
 26     end
 27   end
```

Answer (score 1):

I would probably just place the @user.save in an if statement instead of sending a block to it. Try to do something like this instead:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  if @user.save
    flash[:notice] = "Account registered!"
    redirect_back_or_default campaign_path
  else
    render :action => :new
  end
end
```